# Python openpyxl dimensions are one more in rows and columns

Tags: openpyxl

The openpyxl worksheet dimensions seem to be one more in rows and columns than the actual spreadsheet. For instance, I created a 3x3 Excel file like below:

```
food | price | weight |
banana | 15 | 20.3 |
orange | 13 | 33.2 |
```

But the openpyxl worksheet ws has the following attributes:

```
ws.max_column = 4
ws.max_row = 4
ws.dimensions = A1:D4
```

Is it done intentionally so that we could use range(1, max_row) and range(1, max_column) to iterate without adding +1?

Comment: Sounds like you added some cells to an existing worksheet. You should almost never need to use `ws.max_row` or `ws.max_column` in your own code.

Comment: Charlie, you are right -- max_row, max_column and dimensions are all in memory read-only attributes. They change as we add a new cell or even just access one. I must have looked up ws["D4"] without setting a value in the shell which makes it a 4x4 ws. Now I saved it to an excel file with "ws["D4"] = None" and then loaded it back, it showed 3x3 this time. So I guess we could still use them so long as we don't add or access new cells to the worksheet. The tutorial has this Note: accessing them directly will create them all in memory, even if you don’t assign them a value.

Answer (score 0):

After more debugging, it is clear that these attributes are in memory and only use them if you didn't add or access beyond what are loaded from an excel file. It is better use your own code like below to find max_row and max_column:

```
def nRows(self):    # Assume Column A has the most rows
    n = 100
    for i in range(1, n):
        rowA = self.ws['A'+str(i)]  # Column A, row i
        if self.ws['A'+str(i)].value is None:
            break
    self.nRows = i - 1
 
def nColumns(self):
    n = 0
    alphabets = [chr(i) for i in range(ord('A'), ord('Z'))] # Assume no more than 26 columns
    for j in alphabets:
        n += 1
        if self.ws[j + str(1)].value is None:   # Column j, row 1 (heading row)
            break
    self.nColumns = n - 1
```

Below are their values after each function call in sequence:
[image]

So if you would print them afterwards with

```
for i in self.ws.values:
    for j in i:
        print(j, end = ' | ')
    print()
```

You get an extra row and column:

```
food | price | weight | None | 
banana | 15 | 20.3 | None | 
orange | 13 | 33.2 | None | 
None | None | None | None |
```